# How to make execution of an external JAR inside Spark code sequential

Tags: java, apache-spark, executable-jar, synchronous, sequential

There is scenario where
At step 1
InvokeTakaraJar(parameter..) is called
Which does the work of updating table with records but this is a normal Java jar and not a Spark code

The at step 2
There is
var df  = GetDBTable(parameter..) which should get the records from the table being updated in above step.

Problem is since the first step is just the invoke of main method of external Java jar, it runs from the driver

And the 2nd step does not wait for completion of the step 1.

Ideally 2nd step needs to wait for the first to complete.

How to achieve this in Spark scala code where there is a requirement to run a different Java jar which needs to complete first and then Spark step should execute.

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn't really do guaranteed order very well.  It actually wants to complete several tasks in parallel.  I would be concerned about running a java program because it may not scale up to be able to complete when you are using data at scale.  (So let's pretend for the sake of the argument your data that java is updating will always be small.)

That said if you need to run this java program and then run spark why not launch the spark job from Java after you have completed your table update?

Why not run a shell/oozie/build script that runs your java program first and then launches the spark job.

If you are looking for performance, consider rewriting the java job so it can be done using spark tooling.

For the absolute best performance see if you can re-write the java tooling so that it's triggered on data entry so that you never need to run it as a batch job, you can depend on the data already being updated.